How do I use VLOOKUP to lookup multiple values if a value is potentially missing?
I have a table with two columns:
account | amount
--------+-------
    525 | 199.12
    400 | 209.23
    410 | 458.78
    415 |  56.10
    150 | 119.60

This data is being pulled in from a SQL server via Power Query. I want to sum the amounts matching certain accounts. I figured that this was easy enough with a VLOOKUP. So I wrote: =SUM(VLOOKUP({"400","410","411","412","413","414","450"},Query1!A:B,2,FALSE)). This works fine except when one of the values in the lookup array is not in the table, which happens if there were no entries to that account during a given time period. I get an "A value is not available to the formula or function" error in that case.
I feel like this is a simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

Look into SUM(SUMIF())

I figured it out. The IFNA function exists for this purpose. New code: =SUM(IFNA(VLOOKUP({"400","410","411","412","413","414","450"},Query1!A:B,2,FALSE),0))

You are looking for numbers not text values. Remove the quotation marks.

Are your account numbers unique? VLOOKUP will only consider the first occurrence for duplicates.

@ReddyLutonadio They are actually text values. I didn't include them in the example, but in the actual dataset some have values like “120R”.

@MGonet Yes, they are unique.
